# "Cómo te lo marcas"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, modismos, expresiones, españa

Mandé una foto de algo que cociné a alguien, y me contestaron con la frase "Cómo te lo marcas!".

Me imaginaba que significa algo como "Qué buena pinta tiene", pero me gustaría saber exactamente qué quiere decir. Me lo dijo una persona de Andalucía, por si es algo que solo se dice en esta región.

Comment: Curioso, yo soy andaluz pero no lo había oído nunca. Yo uso "cómo te lo montas", imagino que con el mismo significado. Más que a la buena pinta, la frase incide en las habilidades del cocinero a la hora de hacer un plato con tan buena pinta.

Comment: Gracias Charlie, pues "como te lo montas" sí había escuchado. Al final me di por vencido y pregunté a la persona que significa, y me dice que en realidad es lo mismo. Además, me dió otros ejemplos de este uso de "marcarse": "se lo marca" y "marcate un baile". Parece que sólo se usa en Sevilla (veo que también vives aquí en Sevilla, por cierto!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Como te lo marcas!" o, como lo oigo yo mas a menudo, "como te lo montas!" quiere decir algo como "Que bien vives!", haciendo referencia como ya has intuído a la buena pinta que tiene la comida.

Answer (score 1):

Quizá la frase encierra la idea de que ponés todo tu empeño, y lográs distinguir tu obra, como que marcás tendencia, o como que dejás tu marca, porque hacés las cosas muy a tu estilo. En el buen sentido claro.

Debe ser algo regional, a veces acá en mi ciudad hacen frases nuevas cada temporada, que a veces surgen entre amigos, pero en este caso que te relato, no es un decir extendido.